# How to add custom advanced Logging fields on IIS using VSTS release task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-task

I am deploying IIS application/website from VSTS Release management (using VSTS tasks). However, I need to add advanced logging fields on IIS. Could not find a suitable VSTS task for this.

Can anybody suggest something?

Comment: Write a script that does it.

Comment: @DanielMann any pointer for that?

Comment: Your search engine of choice is a fantastic place to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a powershell script task which call [Appcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe) to set the custom logging field or create a console application to do this and call it during the build/release. Sample code here: [Adding Custom Fields to a Log File for a Site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/logfile/customfields/add#sample-code) .